# Multiple Inheritance & Usage of Super Function In Python

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, superclass

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Test1:

    def __init__(self, school, university):
        self.school = school
        self.university = university

    def get(self):
        print('josh')

class Test2(Test,Test1):

    def __init__(self, name1, age1, school1, university1):
        super().__init__(name = name1, age = age1 , school = school1,  university = university1)


t = Test2('john', 16, 'Harvard', 'Yale')
```

Why can't I assign a value to a parent class attribute? For example, for the above classes, why can't I perform the below?

```
t.school # returns error 
t.university #returns error
```

But, the following are valid?

```
t.name
t.age
```

I would like to achieve this, solely relying on the super function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution - this just relies on using the super function to initialise all the (parent class) attributes.

```
   class Test:

        def __init__(self, name, age, **kwargs):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            super().__init__(**kwargs)

    class Test1:

        def __init__(self, school, university, **kwargs):
            self.school = school
            self.university = university
            super().__init__(**kwargs)

        def get(self):
            print('josh')

    class Test2(Test,Test1):

        def __init__(self, name1, age1, school1, university1, **kwargs):
            kwargs['name'] = name1
            kwargs['age'] = age1
            kwargs['school'] = school1
            kwargs['university'] = university1
            super().__init__(**kwargs)

    t = Test2('john', 16, 'Harvard', 'Yale')
    print(t.name)
    print(t.age)
    print(t.school)
    print(t.university)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the constructor for each of the base classes.See here:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Test1:

    def __init__(self, school, university):
        self.school = school
        self.university = university

    def get(self):
        print('josh')

class Test2(Test,Test1):

    def __init__(self, name1, age1, school1, university1):
        Test.__init__(self, name1, age1)
        Test1.__init__(self, school1, university1)


t = Test2('john', 16, 'Harvard', 'Yale')
print(t.name)
print(t.age)
print(t.school)
print(t.university)
```

Comment: Hi Juan David, thanks for answering. I am familiar with the above, but is there a way to do that using a super function instead?

Comment: @Levis1 Why do you need to rely only on the super function?

Comment: No particular reason, actually. Just wanted to better understand how this super function thing works in Python. Your method is much neater in situations like this - I understand.